# Missing text for IMessageService buttons

Tags: mahapps.metro, catel, orchestra

[image]

This is a simple IMessageService.ShowAsync call, with MessageButtons.YesNoCancel, on Windows 7. I'm using Orchestra (Catel) + MahApps Metro shell.

Can the buttons' text be fixed?

Comment: Please report the issue in the official issue tracker at github.com/wildgums/orchestra. Even better, create a Pull Request with the fix ;-)

Answer (score 1):

here is the corresponding issue https://github.com/WildGums/Orchestra/issues/56 and the corresponding pull request https://github.com/WildGums/Orchestra/pull/57.
The PR is already integrated.